# Variable from a plugin into a theme

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

First plugin, basic question... I am trying to print the variable `$xavi` from a **plugin** into a theme like this:

```
add_action('init', '_load_options');

function _load_options() {
  global $xavi;
}
```

So that I can use it in a **theme** file like this:

```
<?=$xavi;?>
```

It doesn't look like [`init`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/init) is the right action hook for this but the only other one that makes sense is `wp_head` and doesn't work either

Any ideas which hook should I use or how should I define variables (maybe through an existing WP function/method instead of creating one from scratch)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your webhost has disabled `register_globals` in the **php.ini**, so you have to "register" your variables manually everytime you want to use it. For example:

```
<?php
global $xavi;
echo $xavi;
?>
```

Another approach is using the `$GLOBALS` array:

```
<?php
echo $GLOBALS['xavi'];
?>
```

But in my opinion, you should avoid using globals. Instead use a simple registry-class, which you can add/get your values.

### EDIT

This isn't a WordPress specific solution and could be a bit of an overkill for this simple question. The registry pattern is an official programming design-pattern. Same goes for the singleton-pattern which I've used here too.

What we do here is to store our content in a registry-object. It's singleton, so only one instance is created.

I know, the problem isn't solved really. Instead of using the $GLOBALS array, we are using a registry class which is indeed also "global" as we call the instance everytime we need it. You don't have control, where you call it. Also the testing of a singleton class could be problematic. If you want more control, just look at the factory-pattern with dependancy injection.

```
class Webeo_Registry {
    /**
     * Array to store items
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    private $_objects = array();

    /**
     * Stores the registry object
     * 
     * @var Webeo_Registry
     */
    private static $_instance = null;

    /**
     * Get the instance
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @access private
     * @return void
     */
    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Set an item by given key and value
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * @param void $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function __set($key, $value) {
        // maybe you want to check if the value already exists
        $this->_objects[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get an item by key
     * 
     * @param string $key Identifier for the registry item
     * @return void
     */
    public function __get($key) {
        if(isset($this->_objects[$key])) {
            $result = $this->_objects[$key];
        } else {
            $result = null;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Check if an item with the given key exists
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * @return void
     */
    public function __isset($key) {
        return isset($this->_objects[$key]);
    }

    /**
     * Delete an item with the given key
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * @return void
     */
    public function __unset($key) {
        unset($this->_objects[$key]);
    }

    /**
     * Make clone private, so nobody can clone the instance
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private function __clone() {}
}
```

In your plugin/theme, you only have to return the instance and you're ready to use it:

```
$registry = Webeo_Registry::getInstance();

// Define some options (just add it after the "->". The magic method __set will do the rest)
$registry->optionA = 'awdawd';
$registry->optionB = array(1,2,3);

// Check the content
print_r($registry);

// Remove an item
unset($registry->optionA);

// Check if option exists
if(isset($registry->optionA)) {
    echo 'option exist';
} else {
    echo 'option does not exist';
}
```

Comment: Interesting... can you show an example of using a class to register variables like that?

Comment: yes please, I've been searching for examples but can't find anything and I'd rather go this way than using globals

Comment: I've added an example of my registry class, which I'm using in my plugins. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a shortcode. The [Wodrpess Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) talks through all the specifics. But basically setup a function that returns your variable. Add the shortcode to wordpress, then call `do_shortcode( '[shortcode]' )` inside your PHP code and you can echo it or store it to process it more. You can use use the shortcode inside content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions in themes. If I'm correct you can add the following in your template:

```
<?php _load_options() ?>
```

Should work. However the _ probably means that it's private, so you might need to make the function public.

Comment: Thanks Jan, although I'd prefer to modify the theme as few as possible (just when echoing the variable)

Answer (score 0):

Inside  your plugin

```
    function wtnerd_global_vars() 
    {        
        global $wtnerd;

        $wtnerd = "I am nerd";    
    }

    add_action( 'parse_query', 'wtnerd_global_vars' );
```

Then print the variable to your template/theme

```
$GLOBALS['wtnerd'];
```

my source: https://gist.github.com/aahan/7444046